# How to concatenate files by calling Windows Shell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, shell

I am trying to write some VBA in Excel that will concatenate .csv files by executing the `copy` and `more` commands in the Windows Shell.

This code successfully creates an empty file `concat_target.txt` (into which the others will be concatenated):

```
Shell ("cmd.exe copy /b NUL " & """\\path\to\network\folder\concat_target.txt""")
```

However, this code does not have the intended effect of saving `file_1.txt` as `file_1.concat_temp` (skipping the header):

```
Shell ("cmd.exe more +1 " & """\\path\to\network\folder\file_1.txt""" & " > " & """\\path\to\network\folder\file_1.concat_temp""")
```

In fact, every variation of the call to `more` that I have tried just pops up a console (that stays open) whereas the call to `copy` does not.  The UNC network path has cursed spaces in it.

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that adding the `/c` flag to the `more` command does the trick (although it seems to have no effect on the call to `copy`).  So this code is having the desired effect:

```
Shell ("cmd.exe /c more +1 " & """\\path\to\network\folder\file_1.txt""" & " > " & """\\path\to\network\folder\file_1.concat_temp""")
```

I will post the full solution for posterity once it is finished.

Comment: That `/c` is not being passed to more.  It's being passed to cmd.exe. Type `cmd /?` in a command window to see what it does.

Comment: Why are you using "more" ? You could use "type" command instead. Type prints the contents of a file without stops.

Comment: @cyberponk: The call to `more` was to skip headers.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. So "type" won´t do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know why you are using 'more', but I would use other methods:

```
Shell ("cmd.exe /c type ""\\path\to\network\folder\file_1.txt"" >> ""\\path\to\network\folder\file_1.concat_temp""")
```

Notes:

- redirecting with '>' will overwrite the file, losing previous contents
- redirecting with '>>' will append the file (concatenate)
- no need to separate every element in your string with " & " if they are all text (but I guess you already knew this)
- no need to create an empty file first.

**UPDATE:**

OP was using 'more' to exclude the .csv table headers, as I hadn´t understood before.
So the 'type' command won´t work in this case.